# How to make a fetch request from localhost to api?

Tags: api, http, request

I am making a barcode scanner app. When I make a fetch request localhost is attached to the front of the api url and it brings back a 404. How do I fix this to where when I make a fetch request it only includes the api url I'm trying to fetch to?

```
export const getUpc = (text) => {
  return dispatch => {
  let url = "api.upcitemdb.com/prod/trial/lookup"

  let req = new Request(url , {
    hostname: 'api.upcitemdb.com',

    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://127.0.0.1:3000'
    },
    mode: 'no-cors'
  })

  let product = null
  fetch(req)
  .catch(err => console.log('error', err))
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res.status)
    if(res.status !== 200){
      return {
        resStatus: res.status
      }
    } else if(res.status === 200) {
      console.log(res)
      return res.json()

    }
  })
  .then(parsedRes => {
    if(parsedRes.resStatus !== 200){
      parsedRes.resStatus === 0 ? dispatch(invalidBarcode('noAPI')) : dispatch(invalidBarcode('invalid'))
    } else {
      product = parsedRes
      console.log(product)
      dispatch(productDetected(product))
    }
  })
  }
}
```

I get this error in the console: 
GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/api.upcitemdb.com/prod/trial/lookup 404 (Not Found)

Comment: The protocol is missing for `url`. Please use `http://api.upcitemdb.com/...` or `https://api.upcitemdb.com/...`

Comment: That worked. Won't be forgetting that ever again. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. I've added an answer to describe the root cause and solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the protocol information is missing in `url`. To make it work, variable `url` should be `http://api.upcitemdb.com/...` or `https://api.upcitemdb.com/...` (depends on what protocol the api.upcitemdb.com server supports).

In [Fetch Standard](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#request-class), the constructor of `Request` is defined as:

> The Request(input, init) constructor must run these steps:
>
> ...
>
> 6. If input is a string, then:
>
>    1. Let parsedURL be the result of parsing input with baseURL.
>
> ...

That is, if `http://` or `https://` is missing, it would take current server as "baseURL" (`http://127.0.0.1:3000/`), and take `api.upcitemdb.com` as part of URL path (rather than hostname).

Comment: the last paragraph solved it for me.  Openweather api provides their url without the http and when I add it on my fetch method, the localhost url is prepended automatically to the api url giving me an error.  Thanks for this point.